# How do I keep score between scenes in Unity dynamically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI bug that I can not figure out. I wish to be able to carry my score over into each scene, while also having each scene independent of one another. If the player chooses to start the game in level 6 he should be able to do so with a clean scoreboard, same as starting at level 1. The score should proceed unitl to transfer until the player dies at which point the score should be set back to 0. To do this I've prefabbed my scoreboard and dropped it into every scene using the singleton pattern to make sure that there are no duplicate scoreboards in the scene. While trying to access my score text UI of type Text using UnityEngine.UI I receive a null reference error when the class is called after loading a new scene. Here are the C# classes defining the methods used in order to implement the functionality and screes snippets of my hierarchy in Unity 2019.4.1f1. I'm also attaching a short youtube video to show you that the score does work in the first scene, however it does not work in any other scene after. I do know that I'm destroying the Text UI at the beginning of every scene if there are multiple. What I do not understand is why the Text UI nested under the Scoreboard Canvas is not finding it's reference on Awake() for every instance created and why it's being called null. I truly appreciate anyone help!

Here are the screen snippets and videos in this order:

1. Youtube video of bug
2. Hierarchy of Scoreboard Canvas
3. Hierarchy of Score Text
4. Scoreboard singleton class (Attached to Scoreboard Canvas)/ ScoreText class (Attached to ScoreText UI)
5. Implementation of classes used to add score upon completion of level in CollisionHandler class

[UI Bug Video](https://youtu.be/O58EwrA7jQ8)

[Hierarchy of Scoreboard Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ALk.png)

[Hierarchy of ScoreText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT318.png)

[Scoreboard Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZzTN.png)

[CollisionHandler class used for implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3ZPf.png)

If these don't help, here is the github link to see the project code:

[Github Project Files](https://github.com/PulsarXray89/3_Project_Boost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why it is not working, I'm not really sure.
But I can tell you some ways around it:
You could try to make a public static instance of your ScoreText inside the script of ScoreText.

```
public static ScoreText _instance;
public static ScoreText instance { get { return _instance; } }
private int score;
private Text scoreText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
```

And access its functions with:

```
ScoreText.instance.AddToScore();
```

It would be cleaner and easier to use, in my opinion.
If you would like to simplify a bit more, you could update scoreText in the update function as well. But since you only add points upon landing in those green zones, your way works fine as well.
Hope I could help.

Comment: I will try to implement this and get back to you with results tomorrow @Weedosaurus. Thank you so much for trying to help me guys I really appreciate it :). I can post the update after I check these answers!

Comment: Amazing man, the only thing that was missing was to reference Text scoreText. Thank you so much! It worked :) Would you mind explaining what you did. I'm new to statics and I don't understand the _instance and instance member variables.

Comment: I'm actually not a pro in this matter either. I just told you the way I always use singletons: for pooling, GameManager, Ads, etc. The basics is creating a public static instance of the script of get and not set. And in awake make sure it is the only one.
Glad I could help :D
If you have any more doubts or if something suddently goes wrong, comment this thread and I'll check it again.

Ps. The instance is to be used, while the _instance is to be internally checked. Or maybe not. As I said, I'm not too sure either. ahah

Comment: Well for not being too sure you did quite well at solving the issue I had been researching for about 8 hours on. All I found was "Use UserPrefs()". I didn't want to store data to the machine though and that's what people weren't understanding. I needed a way around it and you nailed it on the head man. I'm going to research why this is working and if you don't mind. I'm going to post a question somewhere else asking the community why it works and see if I can get an in depth explanation. Thank you again and I will msg here If need be. :)

Answer (score 1):

Store your score in a monobehavior that calls `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);`

This will preserve that object between scene changes. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: The scorboard itself is DontDestroyOnLoad(). Is this not correct practice?